# Scroll to last item in nested recyclerview

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I am building an app in which users can ask questions and reply with answers (similar to Facebook posts with comments).

There is a recyclerview for answers nested within each item inside a recyclerview for questions.

I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks "Reply", the screen will scroll to the last answer of a question (the last answer is indicated by the blue font in the following screen captures):

[Before clicking Reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSYTj.png)

[After clicking Reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv2No.png)

I think these would be the relevant parts of my code to share:

QuestionRecyclerViewAdapter.java:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Question question = mQuestionList.get(position);

    // Question
    int thumbnailSizeDp = 30;
    CircularImage circularImage = new CircularImage();
    circularImage.loadCircularImage(thumbnailSizeDp, question.getCreatorThumbnail(), mContext, holder.questionCreatorThumbnail);
    holder.questionCreator.setText(question.getCreator());
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");

    // Multiply by 1000 since Java is expecting milliseconds
    String dateCreated = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(question.getCreatedAt()) * 1000));
    holder.questionDate.setText(dateCreated);
    holder.questionContent.setText(question.getContent());

    // Last question
    if (position == mQuestionList.size() - 1) {
        holder.questionContent.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    // Answers
    holder.rvAnswers.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
    AnswerRecyclerViewAdapter answerRecyclerViewAdapter = new AnswerRecyclerViewAdapter(mContext, question);
    holder.rvAnswers.setAdapter(answerRecyclerViewAdapter);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView questionCreatorThumbnail;
    TextView questionCreator;
    TextView questionDate;
    TextView questionContent;
    TextView questionReply;
    RecyclerView rvAnswers;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        questionCreatorThumbnail = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_question_creator_thumbnail);
        questionCreator = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_question_creator);
        questionDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_question_date);
        questionContent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_question_content);
        questionReply = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_reply);
        rvAnswers = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv_all_answers);

        questionReply.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Question question = mQuestionList.get(getAdapterPosition());
        String questionId = question.getId();

        // Scroll to last answer
        LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) rvAnswers.getLayoutManager();
        manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    }
}
```

In the onClick method, I have:

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) rvAnswers.getLayoutManager();
manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

which worked just fine in another use case but does not work here and I think it has something to do with the fact that the recyclerview is nested.

I also tried using scrollToPosition but that did not work either.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.